# MySQL - Is a user with the "REQUIRE SSL" option still able to log in without providing any SSL or CA certificate?

Tags: mysql

My MySQL Server has the following parameters configured properly

```
mysql> show global variables like '%have_ssl%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_ssl      | YES   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'ssl_ca';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| ssl_ca        | ca.pem |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'ssl_cert';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| ssl_cert      | server-cert.pem |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'ssl_key';
+---------------+----------------+
| Variable_name | Value          |
+---------------+----------------+
| ssl_key       | server-key.pem |
+---------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show global variables like 'datadir';
+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| datadir       | /dados/ |
+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And those files exists in `datadir`

```
[root@mysqlen1 dados]# ls -l ca.pem server-cert.pem server-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1112 Nov  3 10:28 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1112 Nov  3 10:28 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1680 Nov  3 10:28 server-key.pem
```

Then I create a user:

```
mysql> create user 'teste'@'%' identified by 'teste123' require ssl;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I can connect using the certificates

```
[root@TCCPUC-ENGDADOS:~]# mysql -uteste -p'teste123' -h 192.168.0.110 --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 30
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

But without the certificates as well

```
[root@TCCPUC-ENGDADOS:~]# mysql -uteste -p'teste123' -h 192.168.0.110
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 31
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Is this correct? Can I enforce the user to login only with those certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a user `REQUIRE SSL` does not mean the user requires certificates. SSL is for encrypted transport, but certificates are for authentication.

You can create a user with `REQUIRE X509` option to force clients to use a certificate.